# How to write attachment data?

Tags: python, django, gmail-api

I'm getting attachment data from Gmail, while I'm writing data it is throwing an error

> UnicodeDecodeError 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position
>   14: invalid continuation byte

```
service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',labelIds = ['INBOX'],maxResults=10).execute()
    messages = results.get('messages', [])

if not messages:
    print("No messages found.")
else:
    print("Message snippets:")
    count = 0
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):

    for message in messages:
            msg_dict = {}
            msgbody_dict = {}
            msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()

            ID=message['id']
            payld = msg['payload']
            headr = payld['headers']
            payload_data = payld['body']
            #print('type========================',payld)

            if 'parts' in payld.keys():
                payload_parts = msg['payload']['parts']
                for i in payload_parts:

                    payload_headers = i['headers']

                    for NAME in payload_headers:
                        if NAME['name'] == 'Content-Type':
                            content_type = NAME['value']

                            if 'text/html' in content_type or 'text/plain' in content_type:
                                partstype_dat = i['body']['data']
                                partstype_dat=partstype_dat.replace('-', '+')
                                partstype_dat=partstype_dat.replace('_', '/')
                                payldp=base64.urlsafe_b64decode(partstype_dat)
                                payldp = str(payldp , 'utf-8')
                                msgbody_dict['data'] = payldp
                                payload_pldata.append(msgbody_dict)

                            elif i['filename']:
                                attach_parts = i['body']
                                att_id = attach_parts['attachmentId']
                                att_data = service.users().messages().attachments().get(userId='me', messageId=ID, id=att_id).execute()
                                encydoc_data = att_data['data']
                                doc_data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(encydoc_data.encode('UTF-8'))
                                dcdata = doc_data.decode('ASCII')
                                final_docdata = str(doc_data , 'UTF-8')
                                with open(i['filename'],"w") as f:
                                     f.write(final_docdata)
```

Comment: Please add the _complete_ error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type

```
str = unicode(str, errors='replace')
```

or

```
str = unicode(str, errors='ignore')
```

Note: This will strip out (ignore) the characters in question returning the string without them.

Personally it my favorite since I'm using it as protection against non-ASCII input which is not allowed by my application.

Alternatively: Use the open method from the codecs module to read in the file:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open(file_name, "r",encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as fdata:
```